# .htaccess Rewrite Out A Double Period

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We received some press coverage a few months back, but they mistyped our link as `<a href="http://www..oursite.org/" target="_blank" data-component="externalLink">`

They're a significant outlet and not interested in responding to our request to correct this typo, so we're trying to redirect it on our side. Is the below rule viable or, if not, is this something that we can resolve at all?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.\.oursite\.org
RewriteRule .* https://www.oursite.org [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very sorry but you can't do this with htaccess. The problem is that the request `http://www..oursite.org` never hit your server, and therefor you can't do any redirect.

The Domain `www..oursite.org` has an invalid syntax, so you also can't configure a sub-domain `www..oursite.com` on your DNS server that points to your Web server and than catch the request and do some redirect.

So the only way  is to fix the original link.

Comment: I appreciate the response, and that's what the fear was. I was hoping there might be a htaccess or DNS trick to get it back, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: In some cases it is possible e.g. `wwww.oursite.org` or `www.w.oursite.com` but other not like `www.oursite.comm' or `www.oursitee.com` and also not in your case.